# How to make background image above the fold in CSS?

Tags: css, background-image, fullscreen

I have a background image which is covering 100% of the screen above the fold. The HTML and CSS for the background image is:

```css
.mb {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/Uploads/xyz.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb">
</div>
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in CSS so that it should cover 60-70% of the screen above the fold. I tried resizing the image but still it was unable to make to cover 70-80% of the screen.

Comment: I'm looking forward to see more detailed code including html and related css, not only one css class. It will help us to try your problem.

Comment: @voloshin  I have included my HTML and CSS codes.

Comment: @voloshin xyz.jpg image is covering full screen above the fold. I want to make it cover 70-80% of the screen above the fold.

Comment: @user5447339 what do you mean by fold.?

Comment: So, make `.mb` 70 or 80 `vh` high then, instead of 100% ...?

Answer (score 1):

```
.mb {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/Uploads/xyz.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)